# assign 100 leads to users with a 'commercial executive' profile without using triggers

Tags: apex, lead-assignment

```
global class BGA_AssignLead implements Schedulable{
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        
        AssignLead();
     
    }
    
    public void AssignLead(){
        
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, name FROM User WHERE user.profile.name = 'BGA Ejecutivo comercial'];
        Set<Id>Ids = (new Map<Id,User>(users)).keySet();
        
        List<lead> leads = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead where OwnerId IN :Ids AND Status != 'Convertido'];
        Map<Id, Integer> mapaUser = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        
        for (ID idKey : Ids) {
            Integer cant = 0;
            for (Lead lead : leads) {
                if(lead.OwnerId == idKey) {
                    cant++;
                }
            }
            mapaUser.put(idKey, cant);
        }
        
        List<Lead> resultLead = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead where OwnerId = '0055f000005tl2bAAA' AND  Status != 'Convertido'];
        
        for (ID idKey : Ids) {
            
            Integer total = 100 - mapaUser.get(idKey);
            
            if(total < 100) {
                for (Lead lead : resultLead) {
                    
                    if(total > 100) {
                        break;
                    }
                    
                    if(lead.OwnerId == '0055f000005tl2bAAA') {
                        lead.OwnerId = idKey;
                        total++;
                    }
                    // System.debug('ID: ' + idKey + ', Total: ' + mapaUser.get(idKey));
                }
            }
            //System.debug('ID: ' + idKey + ', Total: ' + mapaUser.get(idKey));
        }
        update resultLead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- Don't use `global` unless you need to. `public` is fine.
- Your first nested loop is very inefficient; you can use an aggregate result query.
- Your second nested loop is also very inefficient; you can remove the values from the list as you go to avoid finding the first match.
- Do not use hard-coded ID values; you should query this from the database.
- Not all leads may be assigned, so this is a rare case when you don't want to use the original query list to update the records.

Here's what I imagine your code would look like:

```
public class BGA_AssignLead implements Schedulable{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        AssignLead();
    }
    public void AssignLead(){
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, name FROM User WHERE user.profile.name = 'BGA Ejecutivo comercial'];
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> leadTotals = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, OwnerId Id
            FROM Lead where OwnerId IN :users AND Status != 'Convertido'
            GROUP BY OwnerId
        ]);
        List<Lead> resultLead = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead where OwnerId = '0055f000005tl2bAAA' AND  Status != 'Convertido'];
        List<Lead> reassignedLeads = new List<Lead>();
        for(User theUser: users) {
            Integer total = (Integer)mapaUser.get(theUser.Id)?.get('sum');
            if(total == null) {
                total = 0;
            }
            while(total < 100 && resultLead.size() > 0) {
                Lead tempLead = resultLead.remove(0);
                tempLead.OwnerId = theUser.Id;
                reassignedLeads.add(tempLead);
                total++;
            }
        }
        update resultLead;
    }
}
```

One final note: this assignment is lopsided, so you may want to consider a more advanced algorithm to evenly distribute leads to top everyone off.

```
public class BGA_AssignLead implements Schedulable{
    public class LeadCount implements Comparable {
        Integer leadCount;
        Id userId;
        LeadCount(Integer leadCount, Id userId) {
            this.leadCount = leadCount;
            this.userId = userId;
        }
        public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
            return leadCount-((LeadCount)o).leadCount;
        }
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        AssignLead();
    }
    public void AssignLead(){
        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, name FROM User WHERE user.profile.name = 'BGA Ejecutivo comercial'];
        LeadCount[] userCounts = new LeadCount[0];
        for(AggregateResult leadTotal:[
            SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, OwnerId Id
            FROM Lead where OwnerId IN :users AND Status != 'Convertido'
            GROUP BY OwnerId
        ]) {
            userCounts.add(new LeadCount((Integer)leadTotal.get('sum'), (Id)leadTotal.get('Id')));
        }
        List<Lead> resultLead = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead where OwnerId = '0055f000005tl2bAAA' AND  Status != 'Convertido'];
        List<Lead> reassignedLeads = new List<Lead>();
        while(resultLead.size() > 0 && userCounts.size() > 0) {
            // Least number of owned leads will be in index 0
            userCounts.sort(); 
            if(userCounts[0].leadCount == 100) {
                // They already have 100 leads
                userCounts.remove(0);
                continue;
            }
            Lead tempLead = resultLead.remove(0); // Remove from list, and reassign
            tempLead.OwnerId = userCounts[0].userId;
            reassignedLeads.add(tempLead);
        }
        update resultLead;
    }
}
```